# Как сохранять состояние RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

На данный момент приложение сохраняет состояние RecyclerView при выходе на рабочий стол через клавишу Home. Однако, если я уйду на другой фрагмент, или выйду на рабочий стол клавишей "Назад", и вернусь обратно во фрагмент- состояние RecyclerView не сохранится!

Как сохраняю сейчас:

```
@Nullable @BindView(R.id.feedList) RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //If we catch an exception, it means that recyclerView is not yet created.
    try{
        outState.putParcelable(RECYCLER_VIEW_STATE, recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState());
    } catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    //If we catch an exception, it means that recyclerView is not yet created.
    try{
        layoutManagerState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(RECYCLER_VIEW_STATE);
    } catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(layoutManagerState != null &&
            recyclerView != null &&
            recyclerView.getLayoutManager() != null){
        recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(layoutManagerState);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(layoutManagerState != null && recyclerView != null){
        layoutManagerState = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
    }
}
```

Comment: объяви глобальную статическую переменную и в нее сохраняй состояние

Comment: Просто я не понимаю. Я сохраняю layoutManagerState в onPause в переменной фрагмента, а в onResume layoutManagerState уже null, хотя по сути, переменные не должны обнуляться при выходе на рабочий стол через back

Comment: @БорисовМакс, Это очень плохой способ.

Comment: @timuruktus, Нажатие кнопки back подразумевает под собой закрытие приложения (если в стеке одна активити, как у Вас). Не вижу смысла сохранять состояние `RecyclerView` в этой ситуации.

Comment: @post_zeew Дело в том, что при открытии другого фрагмента и возвращении обратно, позиция RecyclerView тоже не сохраняется

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете указать в манифесте атрибут `launchMode` равный `singleTop`

`singleTop` —говорит нам о том, что Activity может распологаться в стеке несколько раз. Новая запись в стеке создается только в том случаи, если данная Activity не расположена в вершине стека. Если она на данный момент является вершиной, то у нее сработает `onNewIntent()` метод, но она не будет пересоздана.

Если вам это необходимо только для `BackStack`, то вы можете через intent передать флаг `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`

Comment: Объясните, что делает данный код. Что такое `layoutManagerState`?

Comment: Не то скопировал, простите

Comment: Извиняться нет необходимости. Просто исправьте ответ и добавьте пояснений.

Comment: Исправил , теперь и вы исправляйте;)

Comment: Снова не понятно, как `singleTop` у активити поможет сохранить состояние `RecyclerView` между перезапусками приложения. Ведь автор вопроса об этом спрашивает.

Comment: Фрагмент сохранится в стеке с данными! То есть то что я написал должно помочь автору

Comment: Если активити является единственной в стеке (случай как раз из вопроса), то по кнопке назад оно закроется вне зависимости от `launchMode` и ничего сохранено не будет.

Comment: А блииин , прошу прощения . Это я не увидел